# ATCoder education DP contest Z-frog 3 (By ternary search instead of convex hull optimisation)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

Here is the question link: https://atcoder.jp/contests/dp/tasks/dp_z

Yes, this can be solved by DP with convex hull optimisation trick. But instead of convex hull trick, we can afford a time factor of o(logN). So I want to replace the above optimisation with the ternary search.

Here is my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long
using namespace std;

const int imax=2*1e5+10;

ll dp[imax], a[imax], n, c;

ll sqr(ll a){
    return a*a;
}

ll getCost(int i, int j){
    return dp[i]+sqr(a[j]-a[i])+c;
}

int getMinIndex(int lo, int mid, int hi,int i){
    vector<pair<ll,int>> b={{getCost(lo,i),lo},{getCost(mid,i),mid},{getCost(hi,i),hi}};
    sort(b.begin(), b.end());
    return b[0].second;
}

// ternary search over index 'j' where o<=j<i
int getMinCostFor(int i){
    int lo=0, hi=i-1;
    if(lo==hi)return getCost(lo,i);
    while(hi>lo+2){
        int diff = (hi-lo)/3;
        int m1=lo+diff;
        int m2=lo+2*diff;
        if(getCost(m1,i)>getCost(m2,i))lo=m1;
        else hi=m2;
    }
    return min({getCost(lo,i),getCost(lo+1,i),getCost(hi,i)});
}

int main() {
    cin>>n>>c;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) cin>>a[i];

    dp[0]=0;
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
        dp[i]=getMinCostFor(i);
    cout<<dp[n-1];
}
```

Can anyone tell me whether this is correct approach or not, if not then please provide a valid reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't believe one can guarantee that our distance function is unimodal. While we can ensure that our dp is monotonic decreasing for the set of stones either higher or lower than it so far as we iterate through the array and we know that while iterating from stones closest in height to the current stone to the ones farthest from the height of the current stone, we can not guarantee that the sum of these two distances is unimodal due to the fact that the rate at which the second function grows being less than the rate at which the first function grows at potentially more than one point and vice versa.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).